# Actualizar un registro en la base de datos con ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Lo que busco es actualizar un registro de la base de datos por recomendacion de un programador con mas experiencia que me dijo que usara POST estructure el siguiente codigo.

```
<script>
    $("#txtHoraSalida").val(hs);
            $("#txtGafete").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                    var gafete = $("#txtGafete").val();
                    var datos = {};
                    datos = {
                        hora_Salida: $("#txtHoraSalida").val()
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:49851/api/visita/" + gafete,
                        method: "POST",
                        contenttype: "application/json",
                        data: JSON.stringify(datos),
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data == null) {
                                ocultarPopUp();
                            } else {
                                ocultarPopUpRegistroCompleto();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
</script>
```

lo eh intentado con PUT pero me genera un error 400, con este codigo compilado los modals y todo pero no me guarda la actualizacion del registro a continuacion muestro el codigo que tengo en el controller que llama la funcion actualizar.

```
[HttpPost, Route("{salida}")]
        public IHttpActionResult ObtenerSalida([FromUri]string gafeteId)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gafeteId) == true)
                    return BadRequest();

                string mensaje = string.Empty;
                _visitaService.ActualizarVisita(_visitaService.ObtenerSalida(gafeteId), out mensaje);

                return Ok(mensaje);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

y tambien la funcion que tengo en mi service de donde se llama la funcion actualizar.

```
public Visitas ObtenerSalida(string gafeteId)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new EntradaElectronicaAlmacenEntities())
                {
                    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                    var visita = context.Visitas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Gafete == gafeteId && x.Hora_Salida == null);
                    return visita;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

me faltaba mi codigo de actualizar visita que tengo en mi service eh probado con postman y todo va bien con mi codigo en los service pero quiza falte algo para que trabaje bien con ajax

```
public void ActualizarVisita(Visitas visita, out string mensaje)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new EntradaElectronicaAlmacenEntities())
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    mensaje = "Visita Actualizada de manera exitosa";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Eh modificado el codigo tratando de encontrar lo que falta para que me actualize el registro pero no lo encuentro quiza ustedes que tienen mas experiencia me puedan ayudar a encontrar la porcion de codigo faltante o corregir el que tengo de antemano gracias...

Comment: Tu código está incompleto, efectivamente tienes que usar el método POST, pero falta el código de tu función 'ActualizarVisita' para poder ayudarte.

Comment: tengo ese codigo como lo ves asi en mi service eh usado postman para verificar que funcione y lo hace bien pero ya cuando intento actualizar desde el ajax no me funciona.

Comment: En tu función `ajax` debería ser `contentType` y no `contenttype`, si le estás diciendo que es json porque envías un string?

Comment: en mi codigo esta correcto el contentType y me podrias explicar donde le envio el string